# Java Annotations Logic

Tags: java, annotations

I know this topic may have been discussed here regarding making java annotations that have logic functions and do specific actions based on conditions.

One of the famous examples of course  are junit and hibernate.

I have also seen annotations that when you place on an api of a web service controller that it checks the header for authentication token and if the user was not authorized it would return unauthorized and would not even enter this api.

Also i have seen an android library that does most of the normal application logic with annotations: http://androidannotations.org/   .

Now all of the tutorials i have seen in the internet regarding this topic don't give clear examples for how to implement it with least code and i find in the end that extra code is written which conflicts with the main purpose of using annotations with logic which is saving time in writing more code.

Take for example in this reference http://androidannotations.org/

```
@NoTitle
```

is equivalent to

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in this example they seem just to inject their annotation library , they haven't changed any other thing or added any extra code like for example changing the base class which is activity.

Are things just abstracted too much?

And if so how can i reach this level of abstraction to make something like the android library i mentioned above.

Any design patterns recommended for this?

Comment: Might I recommend the word "useful" instead of "functional" which now means a very specific thing that is full of lambda?

Comment: i think i got you since there is functional interface annotation in java 8 @EdwinBuck

Comment: or did i get you wrong ? ...but i still don't get what you meant by "a very specific thing that is full of lambda?" @EdwinBuck

Comment: In Java 8, "functional" describes more than just an interface or an annotation.  It describes a different type of computational model which is based on lambda calculus.  That's an older definition of "calculus" than what you probably will immediately associate from schooling, as it's not about limits and derivatives, but rather it's the definition of "calculus" which roughly means "a way of calculating".  It is it's own language "category" must like Object Oriented Programming is a (different) language category.

Answer (score 0):

The example that you mentioned, i.e, http://androidannotations.org/ in fact a good implementation of the annotations.

In your example, the Android runtime must be assigning the values to the properties(objects) during runtime, based on the Annotation specified. Methods also can be picked up for execution based on the annotations specified on them.

Annotations, is a simple but powerful concept in Java. You can simplify the usage of your api to a large extent.

Check this post https://devcompass.com/2016/05/08/java-annotations-converting-java-objects-to-excel-data/ for information on how to create annotations from beginning. Checkout the source code zip file at the end of the page.

Trust me, annotations are very simple to learn and they can make a big difference in the source code implementation.